# How to resize image after overlapping in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem that I have two downloaded images on my webpage(second image is overlapped with first image), I have to resize second image which is overlapped, programmatically.
 I don't know how to achieve this?

Please suggest me the right result.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you need to do the resizing dynamically (i.e. you don't know in advance the size of the images)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery library makes it easy to do a thing like this.

If you identify the second image by setting it's id attribute `id='secondImage'`, then you could write something like:

```
$('#secondImage')
 .css('width','200px')
 .cssS('height','100px');
```

However, I want to say that plain CSS is likely a better solution.  With plain CSS, you could just write

```
#secondImage
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
}
```